# Teach Mathematica analytical continuation of the gamma function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement, special-functions, integral-transforms

If I ask Mathematica to compute the gamma function for me

```
Integrate[Exp[-s] s^(a - 1), {s, 0, Infinity}]
```

It dutifully returns to me

```
ConditionalExpression[Gamma[a], Re[a] > 0]
```

However, we all know that we can analytically continue this function to the left half plane (safe for nonpositive integers). I would thus like mathematica to understand that when I type

```
Integrate[Exp[-s] s^(-3/2), {s, 0, Infinity}]
```

I want it to return $\Gamma(-1/2) = -2 \sqrt{\pi} $ to me. (Although I understand that mathematically speaking it might not be strictly speaking correct as the integral really is not convergent.) Similarly, I want it to understand that $\int_0^\infty e^{-s z} s^{a-1} ds \;\;``="\;\; z^{-a} \;\Gamma(a) $ when $a$ is in the left half plane.

How do I efficiently teach Mathematica to recognise this analytic continuation?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Maybe: `LaplaceTransform[s^(-3/2), s, 1]` ?

Comment: `Clear[f]; 

f[a_] = Integrate[Exp[-s] s^(a - 1), {s, 0, Infinity}] // Normal;` Then 

`f[-1/2]` evaluates to 

`-2 Sqrt[Pi]`

Comment: `Integrate[Exp[-s] s^(a - 1), {s, 0, Infinity}, 
 GenerateConditions -> False]` is probably closest in meaning to what you want. There's also `Integrate[Exp[-s] s^(a - 1), {s, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> Re[a] > 0]`.  I don't think there is any way to have it check that the answer is the analytic continuation of the convergent integral.

Comment: These are great suggestions. Exactly what I needed! Thank you.